# Polynomial of even degree with all odd coefficients has no rational roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, ring-homomorphism

I’d like to show from a ring theoretic approach that any polynomial of odd integer coefficients and even degree has no rational roots. This exercise came from Joseph Gallian’s 9th edition of *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*. The textbook solution started by assuming such a rational root $\frac{a}{b}$ exists where $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)=1$ and then plugging it into the polynomial and working it out from there.

Rather than that, I want to use content presented in the section on polynomial rings, which is also where the exercise came from. The following is my attempt to use homomorphisms, polynomial rings, and a certain ideal to complete the exercise.

Let $f(x)=a_mx^m + a_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \cdots + a_0$, where the $a_i \in 2Z+1$ and $m\in 2Z$. Note that the sum of the coefficients is even, or equivalently, $\sum_i a_i \in 2Z$. This will be relevant in a bit.

I want to consider the homomorphism $\psi:Z[x]\to (Z/2Z)[x]$ such that $c_sx^s+c_{s-1}x^{s-1}+ \cdots + c_0 \mapsto (c_s + 2Z)x^s + (c_{s-1}+2Z)x^{s-1} + \cdots (c_0 + 2Z)$.

I also want to consider the ideal $I$ of $(Z/2Z)[x]$ such that $I=\{f\in (Z/2Z)[x] | \sum_j (\alpha_j + 2Z) = 2Z\}$. I got this from the fact that for any commutative ring $R$, $J=\{a_rx^r+\cdots + a_0 \in R[x] | \sum_k a_k = 0\}$ is an ideal in $R[x]$. Still in $R[x]$, $(x-1)$ is a factor of any element in $I$. So in $(Z/2Z)[x]$, it follows $(x-1+2Z)=(x+1+2Z)$ is a factor of any $\psi(f)$ where $f$ is the original polynomial described above.

Now I’m not sure how to turn it back around in the direction of showing some sort of statement contradicting $f$ having any rational roots. My thought process behind this was that I would turn the problem from one about polynomials in $Z[x]$ into another (ideally easier) about quotient ring polynomials - especially after seeing that the coefficient sum was even at first.

Any hints, suggestions, and/or remarks would be appreciated.

Comment: a polynomial of even degree, with odd integer coefficients (so all are nonzero)  has an odd  number of terms. Furthermore, the rational root theorem says that any rational root must be of the form $\frac{a}{b}$ with both $a,b$ odd; and $f(a/b)=0$ if and only if $b^n \; f(a/b) = 0.$    That's about it: odd numbers are nonzero.

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to follow through using the method I posted.

Comment: In the quadratic case, it's easy: the discriminant is $\equiv5\bmod8$ and so cannot be square.

Comment: Note that the sum of the coefficients is **odd**, not even.

Comment: You have an even number of odds, so their sum is even, not odd.

Comment: Not every problem can be made simpler by higher level methods. In this case, the obvious approach is to to reduce the assumed equation to one which equates the sum of an odd numbet of odd integers to zero, contradiction, since the sum of an odd number of odd integers must be odd. Simple and elementary.

Comment: Note that the polynomial in question has $n+1$ terms, so the numbet of terms is odd.

Comment: Whoops, thank you quasi.